# Azure Static Web app doesnt not display the content

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I have a Node.js angular web app created with Azure and deploy in Azure App service through github repository.
The website is not display the content and empty page is displayed though no errors.

Not sure why it is not displaying the content properly. However ,there is a warning that Static content size has increased the limit in the npm build.

I also tried to deploy to Angular app to Azure app service. It is not displaying content as well.
In local it is displaying the angular pages without any issues.

Comment: Could you please share your GitHub Repo.So that we can deploy from our end and check.

Comment: https://github.com/rajmanic15/onlineedusystems-test     is the github repository. Though the deployment is happening.

Comment: check whether you have a content in the default page to display.

Comment: If `index.html` is your default page,I can see you dont have anything to display in the page.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WySDp.png).Try to add some content and check once.

Comment: Its a angular page so  page is fine. Still issue there in Static web app. However got it working with Azure web app deployed from VS code.

Answer (score 0):

A build system called [Oryx](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx) is utilised in the default publish process for Azure Static Web Apps. If you investigate the Oryx logs in the GitHub action workflow it may give a clue to any failures.

As part of your troubleshooting, it would be worth skipping the build capability and focussing on the hosting/serving element. I have had issues with it previously, and for some sites have opted out of it running, doing the build in 1 of 2 ways;

1. Building and storing the site assets in a _site directory in the repo
2. Building the site assets in an earlier step in the GitHub action workflow

Below is a screengrab of my GitHub action config for the first of these options. Note the `action` and `skip_app_build` parameters being set.

[image]